# MySQL garbled data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, uwamp

I have a server running UwAmp and I was using phpMyAdmin to run a database. When I was looking through it, I noticed it was using utf_16_swedish_ci. It was working perfectly fine, however I wanted to change it to utf_16_general_ci like we had been told to for this project. when I did, this happened to my data:

[image]

I changed it back to Swedish, but the data is the same. Is there any way to fix this other than individually editing each entry?

Comment: You could restore this table from your last backup, which of course you took before playing with anything this serious right?

Comment: @RigssFolly honestly i did this with my teacher and they said to just do it. This is just for a school project, not that big, but my table has 30 entries and i would like to understand what happened here. It won't be horrible if I end up just having to type it all back in manually.